# nodejs loopback app not loading

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm following the tutorial here http://www.kogonuso.com/2015/09/nodejs-building-restful-apis-using.html to create rest api using loopback. I installed strongloop and loopback and then created an app using

```
slc loopback
```

and ran server using

```
node .
```

but when I go to http://localhost:3000/explorer/
it doesnt load. the chrome loading circle just moves around indefinitely

Comment: have you tried on any different browser?

Comment: I tried it on firefox, but still, no luck. I think there's something wrong with the code. Though I haven't wrote any yet.

Comment: if you haven't done any coding, then there is no problem at your end. by the way did you changed the project name? if yes, did you change the directory to your project?

Comment: yes i changed the project name, otherwise it will use Desktop. And yes I cd to the directory created before running node .

Comment: try installing again as I was not able to replicate your problem? I'm posting in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall strongloop and loopback:

```
npm uninstall -g loopback
npm uninstall -g strongloop
```

upgrade you node.js and npm:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable

npm install -g npm
```

Install only strongloop, you don't need to install loopback separately:

```
sudo npm install -g strongloop
```

Confirm installation by checking slc version:

```
slc --version
```

Now you can follow the tutorial you were using. You don't need to install errorhandler, cookie-parser and loopback separately.

Comment: I followed your instructions and confirmed installation by this slc version: strongloop v5.0.1 (node v4.2.1). But no luck. /explorer still wont load.

Comment: can you provide the output on console when using `node .`?

Comment: Web server listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3000
Browse your REST API at http://0.0.0.0:3000/explorer

Comment: The problem is not with loopback. I used the guest account and it loads without problem. But I need to get this working on my main user account because all my projects are there.